# Difference in css-positioning in windows and linux

Tags: css, linux

I have a problem with rendering my html page by the same browsers in different OS. 
There are 3 spans and position of each span is corrected through css(position:relative).
But I have found out that the page that looks correct in firefox under Linux, shows not right at the same firefox(3.5.7) under Windows OS.

Linux(Left - How it should be)/Windows(right): [link text](http://img62.imageshack.us/img62/5686/linwin.png)

And the same with other browsers. What is the cause of this problem and how is possible to solve it.
My code:
question.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
        <title>Question</title>
        <link href="css/question.css" rel="stylesheet" media="all" />
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="eventFullDate">
            <span class="eventYear">2010</span>
            <span class="eventDate">17</span>
            <span class="eventMonth">FEB</span>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

question.css:

```
html, body{
    font-family: Georgia;
}
div.eventFullDate{
    height: 39px;
    width: 31px;
    float: left;
    border: 1px solid;
    border-color: #E3E3E3;
    background-color: #F7FFFF;
}

span.eventYear, span.eventDate, span.eventMonth{
    color: #EC5C1D;
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
}

span.eventYear{
    left: 1px;
    bottom: 3px;
    font-size: 0.8em;
}

span.eventDate{
    left: 5px;
    bottom: 12px;
    font-size: 1.3em;
}

span.eventMonth{
    left: 3px;
    bottom: 15px;
    font-size: 0.8em;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use a CSS-reset, it will help standardize your css for better cross browser compatibility: http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/reset/

Also, you have this

```
html, body{
 font-family: Georgia;
}
```

I am guessing one of your OS does not have the Georgia font. Probably the Windows one.

Comment: You only don't get a -1 for suggesting the CSS reset hammer because your answer helpfully identifies the font issue.

Comment: Thank you! You are right! There is no Georgia font in my linux system!

Answer (score 2):

It looks like the Linux version is not rendering the Georgia. 
According to the below sources, unless the distro has the MSFONTS, the CSS will fallback to the default serif font.

> Utopia = Georgia (serif)

http://andrew.triumf.ca/fonts/fonts.html
http://mondaybynoon.com/2007/04/02/linux-font-equivalents-to-popular-web-typefaces/

There is one more consideration. Georgia has an old convention of lower-case numbers. The baseline of the digits will vary wildly. For example, the visual baseline for 6 vs. 9 will be very different. You can use your CSS to position one digit, and the other digit will overlap.

My advice is to pick a different font for the large digits or change the design to be less tightly coupled. Georgia is very difficult, if not impossible, to vertically center.

Comment: Thank you for your advice! I will try to use another font for numbers!